# Added a blank row when click button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

In my GridView, I have three status,

1. View Only
2. Edit
3. Add

I want to click a button somewhere in the Grid to insert a new row.
So I have

```
public ObservableCollection<gridDataModel> GridCollection { get; set; }
public void AddNewRow()
{
    GridCollection.Insert(0, new gridDataModel());
}
```

My question is that I want the columns in the first row of the grid can be textbox or dropdown menu. So when I insert the new row I can fill in the data fron the textbox or select value from dropdown menu.

What I did was that I customize the template of the columns. For example

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Databases" Width="498">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DbName}">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                 <Style.Triggers>
                                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewStatus" Value="Visible">
                                         <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"  Value="True" />
                                     </DataTrigger>
                                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewStatus" Value="Visible">
                                         <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"  Value="False" />
                                     </DataTrigger>
                                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AddStatus" Value="Visible">
                                         <Setter Property="IsReadOnly"  Value="True" />
                                     </DataTrigger>
                                 </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>                      
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```

In View Status, every cell is readonly

In Edit status, some columns are read, only. The others can be edited.

The hard part is for add status. I only want the first row(new added row) to be edited status. Which means the first row can be edited, the rest are read only.

How?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MultiDataTrigger` with several conditions. With `MultiDataTrigger` all conditions must be met in order to apply setter (**logical** **AND**).

In your case you need 2 conditions - **RowIndex=0** and **AddStatus=Visible**.
*But, when you adding another row you need somehow disable trigger for the old row.*

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource GetRowIndexConverter}}" Value="0" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding AddStatus}" Value="Visible" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

and converter

```
public class GetRowIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = (ListViewItem)value;

        var listView = (ListView)ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
        int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);

        return index;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
As you really need disabling trigger for old rows (when adding new),
You could use workaround below. But I would consider different solution, more elegant and not that hacky (maybe using code-behind/behaviours)

1) Give a name to your `ListView` (MyListView below).

2) Switch to `MultiBinding` using `MultiValueConverter`.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}" />
            <Binding Path="AddStatus" />

            <!--Count is observable, so every time when collection gets modified system will re-trigger our multi-converter-->
            <Binding Path="Items.Count" ElementName="MyListView" />                                                        
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>

    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

3) MultiValueConverter

```
public class MyMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var listViewItem = (ListViewItem)values[0];

        ListView listView = (ListView)ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(listViewItem);
        int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(listViewItem);

        if (values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            /*i.e. Object1.Object2.AddStatus - if Object2 is null then binding will return UnsetValue */
            return false;
        }

        Visibility addStatus = (Visibility)values[1];

        return index == 0 && addStatus == Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When adding new row `Items.Count` of the `ListView` will re-trigger `MultiValueConverter`

Comment: That is the hardest part, which is to disable  trigger for the old row.

Comment: I updated answer. Not ideal, but should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the nice help. Actually I want to create a property saying`rowNumber` in the model class. So when I create a new row, I can set it as `0` or a special value such as `-1`. For the other rows, the property is a positive integer. If so, then how?